# Cannot read property 'body' of null + passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to implement passport.js in a Node/Express/Sequelize app. I'm trying to stay as faithful as possible to both [the official documentation](http://passportjs.org/docs/configure) and the [Scotch.io tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local), and currently have the following relevant code segments in my scaffolding:

### app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('./config/sequelize');
const config = require('./config/config');
const passport = require('./config/passport');

const app = express();

const port = 3000;

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.listen(port);

app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local', function(req, res, next, err){
    if (err) { console.log(err); }
    res.json(req.body);
}));
```

### ./config/passport.js

```
const db = require('./sequelize');

const passport = require('passport'), 
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    db.User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true  
    }, 
    function(email, password, done){
        process.nextTick(function() {
            db.User.findOne({ email : 'local.email' }, function(err, user) {
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                if (user) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
                } 
                else {
                    db.User.create({
                        username: 'local.email',
                        password: 'local.password'
                    });
                }
            });    
         });
      }
 ));

 module.exports = passport;
```

### ./views/signup.ejs

```
<!-- LOGIN FORM -->
<form action="/signup" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password">
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Signup</button>
</form>
```

With this implementation in hand, I fire up the app, enter the email address and password to sign up on ./views/signup.ejs, and get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null
at C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\repos\chinese-democracy\app.js:45:15
at allFailed (C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\repos\chinese-democracy\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:94:18)
at attempt (C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\repos\chinese-democracy\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:167:28)
...
```

This indicates that req.body is being returned as null, and I have a suspicion it has to do with the manner in which the deserializeUser and serializeUser functions are defined in ./config/passport.js, but how can I get verbose error outputs to determine what the exact cause is? Also, I have done sanity CRUD checks with my Sequelize database so I omitted that file, but will provide it as an edit if any of you think that would be of use in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this in your `app.js` :

```
app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res, next, err){
                                               //^ close
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
});
```

If you need a custom callback:

```
app.post('/signup', function(req, res, next){
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
       //Your code here       
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Please refer to http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate for more details.

Comment: When I implement your first code snippet, I get redirected to BAD REQUEST, and when I do the custom callback with app.post('/signup', function(req, res, next){
 passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info){
  console.log(info);
  if (err) { console.log(err); }
  res.json(req.body);
 })(req, res, next)
}); I get redirected to a completely blank page with no error output

Comment: Try to replace `res.json(req.body)` by `res.json({message:"success"})` just to make sure !

Comment: I don't know what's your aim but in general, when a user is unauthenticated you must redirect him !

Comment: Making the change to res.json({message:"success"}) is shown on the custom callback. My larger aim is to have the user redirected a profile page with their information on it, but I think I still might be facing issues in the fact that req.body appears to be null after the success of authenticate

Comment: I think you need `req.user` not `req.body` ! Please take a look at the answer, I've updated the first snippet !

Comment: The amended first snippet gives "Bad Request" again, but the second one gives req.user is null although req itself is not